# Facing difficulties sending bytes containing white spaces python irc bot

Tags: python, string, socket, irc, chat-command

Trying to make a basic irc bot in python (3.9.2) that can response specific commands when invoked. It works although when a response contains whitespace or a space, only the first word gets displayed by the bot, for example;

```
me > @hello
bot > hi
me > @how is the weather?
bot > the
```

it was supposed to say, `the weather seems nice today`

Here's the code

```
import sys
import time
import socket
import string

server_address="irc.libera.chat"
server_port = 6667

botnick="lamebot"
channel_name="##megadouched"

irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((server_address,server_port))
irc.setblocking(False)
time.sleep(1)

irc.send(bytes("USER "+botnick+" "+botnick+" "+botnick+" bot has joined the chat\r\n", "UTF-8"))

time.sleep(1)

irc.send(bytes("NICK "+botnick+"\n", "UTF-8"))
time.sleep(1)

irc.send(bytes("JOIN "+channel_name+"\n", "UTF-8"))

irc_privmsg = 'b"PRIVMSG "+channel_name+" Hello\r\n"'

while True:
    try:
        text = irc.recv(4096)
    except Exception:
        pass
    if text.find(bytes(":@hi", "UTF-8"))!=-1:
        irc.sendall(bytes("PRIVMSG "+channel_name+" Hello\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        text=b""
    elif text.find(bytes(":@how is the weather?", "UTF-8"))!=-1:
        irc.sendall(bytes("PRIVMSG "+channel_name+" the weather today seems nice\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        text=b""

input()
```

Comment: Looking briefly at the protocol, the examples have a `:` character before the text message.

Comment: @icarus holy!! it works!! Thank you! Would you mind writing a proper answer so I could mark it as accepted one?

Comment: @ilkkachu has beaten me to it. I suggest accepting that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IRC protocol splits the messages into a command and a number of parameters, separated by whitespace. To allow for a trailing parameter that can contain whitespace itself, the protocol allows prefixing that with a colon. Like in this example in [RFC 2812](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2812):

```
PRIVMSG Angel :yes I'm receiving it !
                                   ; Command to send a message to Angel.
```

Now that I looked, that's not actually spelled out too well in the RFC, but hidden in the BNF syntax for the messages at 2.3.1:

```
    params     =  *14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE ":" trailing ]
               =/ 14( SPACE middle ) [ SPACE [ ":" ] trailing ]

    middle     =  nospcrlfcl *( ":" / nospcrlfcl )
    trailing   =  *( ":" / " " / nospcrlfcl )
```

The `trailing` syntax element can appear at the end of `params` after a colon, and unlike `middle`, it allows for the space too.

(Yes, that means that a message like `PRIVMSG someone the weather today seems nice` has more parameters than the `PRIVMSG` command takes, but for whatever reason, that's not treated as an error. Might be just simplicitly of the implementations, or silliness resulting from Postel's law.)

Comment: i guess people are still inside me. sad face :(

Comment: @losethos, I have no idea what you mean with that?